# Html width 100% on image not spreading across the page

Tags: html, css

I have a background image:

```
    <div style="background-image: url(images/Home/diamond.png); height: 2600px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

On the page the image covers all the center and right, but not the left. When I tried width 100%, it did not spread across the page like my other div. If this helps, this div element is a child of a section element and a parent of many other multiple div elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tydj6pcj/  problem is somewhere else - is your div child of another element?

Comment: Yes it is a child of the section element

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
html { 
      background: url(images/Home/diamond.png) no-repeat center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
div
{
    background: url("images/Home/diamond.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width:100vw;` this can work for you.